# Incorrect row numbers MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following table in MySQL:

```
+--------------------------------------------------+
+  id  | type | recordTimeMS | created             +
+--------------------------------------------------+
+  172 | 3    | 125015       | 2020-11-15 20:23:45 +
+  159 | 3    | 116828       | 2020-11-15 20:56:24 +
+  151 | 3    | 115015       | 2020-11-15 22:23:45 +
+  171 | 3    | 136828       | 2020-11-15 21:56:24 +
+ ....                                             +
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

And I'm trying to order it by recordTimeMS and by created, and also get the row nomber (as rank) using this select:

```
SELECT @row_number := @row_number + 1 as rank, utr.id, utr.recordTimeMS, utr.created 
    FROM UserTimeRecord utr,
        (SELECT @row_number:=0) rn
    WHERE type = 3
    ORDER BY utr.recordTimeMS, utr.created
    LIMIT 10
```

The elements are ordered correctly but the rank is incorrect, here's the result:

```
+--------------------------------------------------+
+  rank | id  | recordTimeMS | created             +
+--------------------------------------------------+
+    3  | 151 | 115015       | 2020-11-15 22:23:45 +
+    2  | 159 | 116828       | 2020-11-15 20:56:24 +
+    1  | 172 | 125015       | 2020-11-15 20:23:45 +
+    4  | 171 | 136828       | 2020-11-15 21:56:24 +
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

What causes this and is there another way to do it?

Comment: If you're using MySQL 8.0 you should use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function instead of a user variable.

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() worked like a charm and made things a lot simpler, if you add it to your answer I'll accept it. Final working query: SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY recordTimeMS, created) as rank, utr.id, utr.recordTimeMS, utr.created 
    FROM UserTimeRecord utr
    WHERE type = 3
    LIMIT 10

Comment: You can post your own answer. I don't have much expertise in using window functions; I know enough about them to recommend them, but not write the code myself.

Comment: That's why I gave you the code in the comment :) but yea, I posted it myself now, thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Barmar for pointing me to the ROW_NUMBER()-function, it made it a lot simpler:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY recordTimeMS, created) as rank, 
        utr.id, utr.recordTimeMS, utr.created 
    FROM UserTimeRecord utr 
    WHERE type = 3 
    LIMIT 10
```

And produces the correct result:

```
+--------------------------------------------------+
+  rank | id  | recordTimeMS | created             +
+--------------------------------------------------+
+    1  | 151 | 115015       | 2020-11-15 22:23:45 +
+    2  | 159 | 116828       | 2020-11-15 20:56:24 +
+    3  | 172 | 125015       | 2020-11-15 20:23:45 +
+    4  | 171 | 136828       | 2020-11-15 21:56:24 +
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the ordering in a subquery, and the row number calculations in the main query.

Otherwise, in some circumstances MySQL will do the `@row_number` assignments first, and then perform the ordering after substituting those into the result set.

```
SELECT @row_number := @row_number + 1 as rank, utr.id, utr.recordTimeMS, utr.created 
FROM (
    SELECT id, recordTimeMS, created
    FROM UserTimeRecord 
    WHERE type = 3
    ORDER BY recordTimeMS, created
    LIMIT 10
) AS utr,
(SELECT @row_number:=0) rn
```